# How to import bulk products in Facebook shop?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, codeigniter-3

Im using codeigniter3. Its E-commerce website and have above 7000 products. Facebook shop option don't allow to upload bulk products. its just allow to upload 1 product at a time. Its very hard to upload 7000 products manually.
Kindly give me some sample or right path to achieve this goal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step by step...

1. Open Business Manager > Assets > Catalogues
2. Locate the catalogue used for the Facebook Shop Tab (you will need at least one product in your Facebook Shop for the catalogue to appear)
3. Click the Catalogue Name and navigate to the Product Data Sources tab
4. Add Data Source > Add New Product > Use Data Feed **
5. Download the CSV Template and fill in the required columns.
6. On the same page, Choose "Upload Once", Upload the file, give it a name, set the currency and Start Upload

You're all done!

**If you already have a product feed set up so you can tag products in posts, you can use the same data source and point it to your shop tab:

1. Locate the catalogue feed coming from your website
2. Click the Catalogue Name and navigate to the Product Data Sources tab
3. In the "Last Update" column, there will be a URL, COPY THAT url.
4. Go back to Business Manager > Assets > Catalogues
5. Locate the catalogue used for the Facebook Shop Tab
6. Click the Catalogue Name and navigate to the Product Data Sources tab
7. Add Data Source > Add New Product > Use Data Feed
8. Choose "Set a Schedule"
9. Paste the copied URL in to "Data Feed URL" (you won't need a username or password)
10. Set the schedule, Give it a name, Set the currency and Start Upload

You're all done!

If you need any help, give me a shout!

Comment: Please let me know how you get on and don't forget to upvote so others can see the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Do you guys know how to bulk upload products  images to facebook shop?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public API for this. You will have to apply for the Alpha here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/shops-api

> Currently, businesses can create a Shop section on a Page via self-serve Page publishing tools or through select third party eCommerce platforms like Shopify. We're now expanding our alpha test to additional third party eCommerce platforms. Through this API, platforms can offer their merchants the ability to sell products right on their Facebook Page via the same tools they are using to manage their eCommerce business.

Thanks

Comment: Facebook removed this api?

Comment: Yes, they have removed the API.